How to show index.html on every request in vanilla JavaScript
I'm working on a project using vanilla JavaScript. I want to build a spa(single page application) router.
If you visit the pages by clicking on one of links, the screen is not re-rendered. But if you visit it by directly entering the path, you will get to see the message Cannot GET /seller.
This is because I haven't created a seller.html file, and I want to implement a spa router by showing index.html on every request. How can I do this?


const route = (event) => {
  event = event || window.event;
  event.preventDefault();
  window.history.pushState({}, "", event.target.href);
  handleLocation();
};

const routes = {
  404: "pages/404.html",
  "/": "pages/loginPage.html",
  "/seller": "pages/sellerPage.html",
  "/block-list": "pages/blockListPage.html",
  "/customer": "pages/customerPage.html",
};

const handleLocation = async () => {
  const path = window.location.pathname;
  const route = routes[path] || routes[404];

  const html = await fetch(route).then((data) => data.text());
  document.getElementById("main-page").innerHTML = html;
};

window.onpopstate = handleLocation;
window.route = route;

handleLocation();
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ko">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vanilla JS SPA</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="/" onclick="route()">login</a>
    <a href="/seller" onclick="route()">seller</a>
    <div id="main-page"></div>
    <script src="router.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>




setup up node server simply for this

Thank you for your reply. Can I get some more hints?

@myeongin There is no vanilla js solution for this. You have to implement the sever side for handling those custom routes as well. But if you're planning to use this in a react app, I suggest looking into react-router-dom since it already handles the complexity of routing for you.

yes i am mentioning the answer do let me know if you need further help

initialize
npm init -y

install express
npm install express

make server.js file
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server on port ${PORT}`);
});

make router.js
const route = (event) => {
  event = event || window.event;
  event.preventDefault();
  window.history.pushState({}, "", event.target.href);
  handleLocation();
};

const routes = {
  404: "pages/404.html",
  "/": "pages/loginPage.html",
  "/seller": "pages/sellerPage.html",
  "/block-list": "pages/blockListPage.html",
  "/customer": "pages/customerPage.html",
};

const handleLocation = async () => {
  const path = window.location.pathname;
  const route = routes[path] || routes[404];

  const html = await fetch(route).then((data) => data.text());
  document.getElementById("main-page").innerHTML = html;
};

window.onpopstate = handleLocation;
window.route = route;

handleLocation();

and last but not the least your index.html file
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ko">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vanilla JS SPA</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="/" onclick="route(event)">login</a>
    <a href="/seller" onclick="route(event)">seller</a>
    <div id="main-page"></div>
    <script src="router.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

in last run this command in terminal
node server.js

remember your file structure must look like the way i have mentioned
/public
    /pages
      .html files
       i.e index.html
  router.js
  server.js
  package.json

